# How much is "eine gewisse"?

Tags: translation, usage

I sometimes hear sentences like:

> Er bezahlte eine gewisse Summe, um [...]
>   Nach einer gewissen Zeit wurde ihm klar, [...]
>   Eine gewisse Menge Lösung wird benötigt, um [...]

Now this "*gewisse"* seems not to be a precise measure in the sense of *"Gewissheit"* but rather a not so clearly defined amount of something.

When should I use this expression? Does it refer more to a large amount or rather to a small amount?

Comment: How do you define a large amount, how a small amount?

Comment: Eigentlich besagen die obigen drei Fügungen nichts und sind eher als ungenaue Rederei anzusehen. Nach einer gewissen Zeit ist nach einiger Zeit, eine gewisse Summe ist Gerede, ebenso eine gewisse Menge. Ich würde solche vagen Fügungen nicht verwenden.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Gewiss* is an adjective that suggests a fixed, but not precisely mentioned (not necessarily unknown) amount of something. The amount is not necessarily large; it is typically *above average* or *more than nothing* and indicates that there *is* an amount (as opposed to nothing) or that the amount is higher (than expected, for example). *Bestimmt* is kind of similar, but emphasizes that the amount is known and fixed (and does not suggest it to be greater or less), while *gewiss* mostly suggests a *greater* amount. It depends on context whether *gewiss* suggests greater or smaller amounts, or neither.

---

From the samples:

*Eine gewisse Summe* means it wasn't free, but not necessarily a huge amount. It is often used to indicate that you have to pay more for better things:

> Man bekommt zwar für 100 Euro ein Handy, aber *eine gewisse Summe* muss man *schon* anlegen, um etwas Anständiges zu bekommen.

*Schon* emphasizes that the amount is larger, but is not necessary here and may be colloquial. You'll often hear it in sentences like this though.

*Eine gewisse Zeit* means it wasn't instantly or fast:

> Ich dachte, ich könnte auf GL&U schnell eine Antwort schreiben. *Eine gewisse Zeit* habe ich dann aber doch benötigt.

*Eine gewisse Menge Lösung* means you need some solution, maybe more than initially thought:

> Ein paar Tropfen reichen nicht. Man muss *eine gewisse Menge* Lösung anwenden, um ein sichtbares Ergebnis zu erzielen.

The third example could also be changed to use *bestimmt*:

> Man muss *eine bestimmte Menge* Lösung anwenden (nicht zu viel, nicht zu wenig), um ein sichtbares Ergebnis zu erzielen.

*Gewiss* can be inverted, for example by using *nur*:

> Man braucht *nur eine gewisse Menge* Lösung anzuwenden.

This means that you need less than thought.

---

However, *gewiss* can not only refer to amounts, but also to other things and then has the original meaning of something *known*, but not mentioned (which is, of course, similar to the meaning explained above). For example:

> Ein gewisser Kunde findet es sehr lustig, immer kurz vor Feierabend anzurufen.

The addressed person may or may not also know said customer in this case. This can be used to talk about the customer without saying the name.

> Zu einer gewissen Zeit kann man auch mal schlafen gehen.

This suggests that you're staying awake for too long. The exact time is irrelevant.

Comment: Great answer; only one thing where I can't agree: If I read "Man braucht nur eine gewisse Menge Lösung anzuwenden", then I read it as "It suffices to apply a certain amount of the solution". What I mean, for me the _nur_ refers to _braucht_ and not to _eine gewisse Menge_. I can't understand it in the sense that less than thought is needed.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Not sure what you mean; if you leave out the "nur" ("Man braucht eine gewisse Menge Lösung") vs. including it ("Man braucht nur eine gewisse Menge Lösung"), the first one suggests greater and the second one suggests less, at least to me.

Comment: To me it suggests that you _only_ need a certain amount of solution and nothing _else_. (So it's not about _more_ or _less_ but about needing other things or not.)

Answer (score 3):

"gewisse" translates very well to "certain" in a lot of contexts....

Comment: This appears to be a good answer, in that it precisely asserts the correspondence to English. I can therefore understand `gewissen` as 'an amount that is well-understood by somebody, but not specified in this conversation'. The oustanding question is, as always: is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Interessanterweise werden die Wörter 'gewiss' und 'bestimmt', obwohl sie Gegenteiliges suggerieren, oft gegenteilig verwendet:

> Wenn Du Dein Fahrrad unabgesperrt irgendwo stehen lässt, musst Du nur eine *gewisse (bestimmte)* Zeit warten, bis es weg ist.

Die Zeit, die man warten muss, ist mitnichten bestimmt oder gewiss. Vielmehr ist sie ungewiss und unbestimmt – sonst könnte man ja sagen "17 Minuten".

Eine Aussage zur Größe ist auch nicht mit dem Wort verbunden. Das hängt sehr vom Kontext ab.

> Du musst schon eine gewisse Menge Rotwein einkalkulieren, um ein anständiges Burgunderboef hinzubekommen.

unterstreicht, dass es vielleicht mehr ist, als der Hörer gedacht hätte, aber `viel` und `wenig` sind natürlich selbst unbestimmte Begriffe.

> Eine gewisse Ersparnis ist mit den Kundenkarten verbunden.

drückt aber aus, dass die Ersparnis gering ist.

> Gewisse GL&U-Benutzer mögen das anders sehen, …

ist eine weitere Verwendung, die dem Angesprochenen sagt, dass er schon weiß, wer gemeint sei. Eine leicht verschwörerische Note begleitet diese Andeutung, die man auch von der Rede über *gewisse* Etablissements kennt, wo manche Frau das *gewisse* Etwas hat.

> Ein gewisser Herr Wulff sagte 2010, man solle den Ehrensold überdenken.

ist eine weitere Konstruktion, bei der das *gewiss* eine Pointe andeutet – hier und oft eine Ironie. Es kann sich aber auch auf die Prominenz dessen beschränken, von dem die Rede ist:

> Gestern war ich in der Stadt, und traf einen gewissen Linus Thorvald.